# on-click checked/unchecked works for 2 times only then not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**set check** working for two time only. 

->once it checked
-> then unchecked 
but i want this something like toggle. please fix this code.

```js
$('#a').click(function() {
  if ($("#radioinstant").is(':checked')) {
$("#radioinstant").removeAttr('checked', 'checked'); //This line
}else{
$("#radioinstant").attr('checked', 'unchecked');
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    With JQuery Function: <input type="checkbox" id="radioinstant"/>
    <a id="a" href="#">set check</a>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the logic by providing a function to the `prop()` class which inverts the current setting. Try this:

```js
$('#a').click(function() {
  $("#radioinstant").prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
    return !checked;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  With JQuery Function:
  <input type="checkbox" id="radioinstant" />
  <a id="a" href="#">set check</a>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome its working :)

Comment: This would also work     $('#a').click(function() {
      $("#radioinstant").prop('checked',!$("#radioinstant").is(":checked"));
    });

Comment: That would work, but it makes two queries to the DOM to get the `#radioinstant` element. The method in my answer only makes 1 DOM query.